# infimum and supremum of riemann sum

Tags: supremum-and-infimum, riemann-sum

I saw this example on internet as I was studying for my exam. I am a little bit confused as why the supremum is 1 and infimum is 0? Also at the end it has a conclusion that f is not integrable in [2,3], is it because L and U have different answers? Please help me to clarify this. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: If it is Riemann integrable then as the partition gets sufficiently fine, then the upper sum should approach the lower sum.  But in this case, they don't.

Comment: Let me confirm: You are not sure why the supremum of $f$ over any  such  interval contained in $[2,3]$ is $1$, and why the infimum is zero? For the second question, you are right. $1 \neq 0$, so the upper and lower Riemann sums don't coincide, hence the function isn't integrable.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Yes I am not sure why the infimum and supremum are as such given in the example.. as for the second question it is clear now to me that 1 does not equal 0, thus function f is not integrable. It is just teh infimum and the supremum part confusing me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok then. I will answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll see this in words, and then translate it into mathematical language. Then the supremum/infimum thing will fall out.

> In every interval, we know that there is at least one rational and one irrational. $f(x) = 0$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is irrational.

We have a dissection of $[2,3]$.This will give the intervals $(x_{i-1},x_i)$.

$\sup_{(x_{i-1},x_i)} f(x)$ is the largest value that $f$ takes in this interval. However, this interval contains *at least one* **irrational**, call that irrational $r$ , then $f(r) =1$, where $r \in (x_{i-1},x_i)$. Now, the maximum value $f$ takes *anywhere* is $1$ (from definition), so the supremum of $f$ over *every* interval is $1$, since in every interval, $f$ takes the value $1$ at least once.

Similarly, $\inf_{(x_{i-1},x_i)} f(x)$ is the smallest value that $f$ takes in this interval. However, this interval contains *at least one* **rational**, call that rational $s$ , then $f(s) =0$, where $s \in (x_{i-1},x_i)$. Now, the minimum value $f$ takes *anywhere* is $0$ (from definition), so the infimum of $f$ over *every* interval is $0$, since in every interval, $f$ takes the value $0$ at least once.

Now, we have from the definition of $\mathcal U(f,D)$ (*for all dissections $D$*):

$$
\mathcal U (f,D) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (x_{i} - x_{i-1}) \left(\sup_{(x_{i-1},x_i)} f(x)\right) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (x_{i} - x_{i-1}) \times 1 = 3-2 = 1
$$

Now, we have from the definition of $\mathcal L(f,D)$ (once again, for all dissections $D$):
$$
\mathcal L(f,D) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (x_{i} - x_{i-1}) \left(\inf_{(x_{i-1},x_i)} f(x)\right) = \inf_{i=0}^{n-1} (x_{i} - x_{i-1}) \times 0 = 0
$$

This is essentially what is happening in the proof.

Comment: @actoh this is brilliant. Thank you so much..

Comment: You are welcome!